# What happens when stderr redirected after stdout?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

What happens when `stderr` is redirected after `stdout` and vice versa?

For example:

`someCommand > log.txt 2>&1`

vs.

`someCommand 2>&1 > log.txt`

Answer (score 5):

Redirecting is done in the order of appearance:

```
someCommand > log.txt 2>&1
```

- stdout is file descriptor 1 `fd(1) == stdout`
- stderr is file descriptor 2 `fd(2) == stderr`
- redirecting file descriptor 1 to `log.txt` results in `fd(1) == log.txt`
- redirecting file descriptor 2 to file descriptor 1 results in `fd(2) == fd(1) == log.txt`
- resulting in everything that is written to file descriptor 1 or 2 is actually written to log.txt.

```
someCommand 2>&1 > log.txt
```

- stdout is file descriptor 1 `fd(1) == stdout`
- stderr is file descriptor 2 `fd(2) == stderr`
- redirecting file descriptor 2 to file descriptor 1 results in `fd(2) == fd(1) == stdout`
- redirecting file descriptor 1 to `log.txt` results in `fd(1) == log.txt`
- resulting in everything that is written to file descriptor 1 is actually written to log.txt
- and everything that is written to file descriptor 2 is actually written to stdout

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, stdout is directed to the file `log.txt` and then stderr is directed to what stdout is attached to (the file `log.txt`).  In the second case. stderr is directed to the thing that stdout is attached to (probably a tty), and then stdout is directed to the file `log.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

`someCommand > log.txt 2>&1` - stdout and stderr both to `log.txt`.

`someCommand 2>&1 > log.txt` - stdout to `log.txt`, stderr to former stdout (screen).